# Where to put font-face in CSS?

Tags: css, font-face

When you add `@font-face` into your site's single css file where is the best place to put it? Top of the css file? Bottom?

If you put it at the top I would think it would slow down the loading of the css. If you add to the bottom then all the text would load the fall back fonts until the fonts were loaded which wouldn't be optimal either. So when using `@font-face` and not TypeKit, GoogleFonts, etc, where should you put it?

*Update - To reaffirm the above this is in reference to where to put `"@font-face{font-family:'Ave Regular';src:url('fonts/ave-regular.eot?#iefix')....etc"` in the css file, not where to put the body `"{ font-family: fontname, arial, serif } etc"`. And that I understand it "can" go anywhere and work, and whether I put at top or bottom or in the middle won't make "much" of a difference but looking for which is better no matter how marginally or if it one way is better depending on certain use cases.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> If you put it at the top I would think it would slow down the loading of the css.

No, it does not. The browser isn't going to wait to download the fonts first before loading the rest of your stylesheet. It'll start downloading the fonts asynchronously, but those font downloads don't interfere with anything but page rendering (see [FOUT](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout)).

If you meant to say that having the rules at the top would slow it down because the browser has to download the rules first before the rest of your stylesheet, that really doesn't matter unless you have tens of kilobytes of `@font-face` rules (very, very, very unlikely).

There are no rules governing where to place `@font-face` in a stylesheet, but I generally keep most at-rules at the top for organizational purposes.

Comment: Yeah so far the very top of the css file seems then to be the most optimal since the fonts can start downloading immediately and won't prevent the css from loading. Will wait to see if anyone has any alternative thoughts before accepting. Thank you!

Comment: I know, this is old, but Googles PageInsights marks the fonts as "blocking resources" if on top of CSS

Comment: Here's a source that argues inlining `@font-face` in the main HTML file: https://web.dev/font-best-practices/ ... This makes a lot of sense if, for example, your `@font-face` code takes up 300 bytes and your external CSS file is 30KB -- by inlining the browser doesn't have to download 30KB in order to process the `@font-face` inside it.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016, modern browsers actually prevent the FOUT (Flash of Unstyled Text) by hiding the text (making it transparent). (Chrome for example waits 3 seconds, then uses the fallback font if the proper font hasn't loaded by then.) This is allowed by the CSS3 spec.

> In cases where textual content is loaded before downloadable fonts are available, user agents may render text as it would be rendered if downloadable font resources are not available **or they may render text transparently with fallback fonts to avoid a flash of text using a fallback font**.
>
> [CSS Fonts Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-face-loading) (emphasis added)

But this behaviour in effect trades the FOUT (Flash of Unstyled Text) with the [FOIT](https://www.viget.com/articles/the-font-face-dilemma) (Flash of Invisible Text) and leaves users on really bad connections worse off than with the FOUT.

Also, see [this clever workaround](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html) (requires JS).

Answer (score 0):

Whether you put it at the top or bottom it will have to load some time eventually, so I don't think it really matters.  If you are super concerned with performance, I recommend combining all of your CSS into one file and minimizing it.  This way, the requests to the server are limited to one, instead of 10 (for 10 different CSS files containing different fonts and such).

Read this:

> With stylesheets, progressive rendering is blocked until all
>   stylesheets have been downloaded. That’s why it’s best to move
>   stylesheets to the document HEAD, so they get downloaded first and
>   rendering isn’t blocked. With scripts, progressive rendering is
>   blocked for all content below the script. Moving scripts as low in the
>   page as possible means there's more content above the script that is
>   rendered sooner.

Ref.  http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

Comment: Yes as noted I'm already online using a "single css file". My question is where to put it since I can techinically put it anywhere this question is which location is best. Just like JS can go anywhere but it's best to put it at the end of the html file.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  CSS shouldn't be treated like javascript.  HTH

Comment: I was just comparing to JS in that certain types of files such JS are recommended to go in a certain location even though they can technically go anywhere, just like css could techinically be loaded at bottom of html file but recommended to have it at top. My question is about where in the css "@font-face" should go (not where css or js get's called in).

Comment: I believe the answer is that since stylesheets are not progressively rendered, it does not matter where you put font-face.

Comment: If I added it to the bottom of the css then it wouldn't attempt to start downloading the font-face fonts until it finished loading all of the css compared to starting it instantly. So that would make a difference in the loading of the fonts to the user. So far putting them at the top as suggested by another user seems to make the most performance gains.

Comment: Well, that's interesting, anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I would say...you keep your font inside the body{ font-family: blahblahblah;}

Comment: font-face that calls the font can't go inside of body { } in css. This question isn't about "font-family: font-name..." it's about the @font-face code used to load the actual CSS font files.

Answer (score -2):

Out of convention, its best to use font-face at the top of the file, because it most likely won't change often, but if it does it has a lot of impact (visually) on your application.

I usually include it either in `body{}` or `html{}`

In terms of **performance ** it most likely doesn't matter much. As far as maintainability for yourself, it'd be best in terms of your mental performance to have it at the top so you are not rooting through CSS trying to find something so visually-effective.

This is how I implement this, quick snippet:

```
body{margin:0; font-family: "CiN", Arial;}
@font-face {
    font-family: "CiN";
    src: url('sling.eot');
    src: local('?'), url('sling.woff') format('woff'), url('sling.ttf') format('truetype'), url('sling.svg#webfontJgTq0KbR') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Mental perforamnce isn't a concern as I just do cmd+f and can search for anything, this is just about performance since techinically it can work anywhere. I'm not sure what you mean by in body{} or html{}. The "font-family: fontfacename, arial, serif," etc would go in those as well as all through out the css file, but I'm reffering to the @font-face{font-family:'Ave Regular';src:url('fonts/ave-regular.eot?#iefix')... etc part which can't go inside body { } or html {} in the css. Would have to go above or beneath. But yes so far people say the top. Thanks!

Comment: In that example you are adding it below the body {}. While another user recommends adding them at the top of the css file. Will wait to see what others say and why one may be better than the other.

Comment: Yeah, this snippet is at the top of my CSS file, and that CSS file is referenced in the <head> <!-- css file here--> </head> portion of the page --> which is at the top of the page.

Comment: The top of the page would mean the @font-face would appear above "body { margin.." etc. You have it after. Some people suggest putting it at the very top others somewhere in the middle like your example suggests or some say the bottom. To note, while your example only includes on @ font-face import users may be loading in 2 or 3. and those fonts might not be referenced until later in the css file.